# Problem while training custom yolov_3 using AlexeyAB darknet

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, yolo, darknet

I am creating a Yolov_3 model using darknet on Google Colab
I have done everything right and got pretrained weights to give a head start to the training but at the end while initializing the training it showed this.[image: Custom object detection on Yolov_3]
It ran without error but showed darknet is directory.
What am I doing wrong.

Solved it by just entering into the darknet directory. As the terminal was outside and wasn't able to look for it

Answer (score 1):

I think that the model you created is saved in the file /media/files/darknet35.conv.74
so you will have to download it ( i think ) and then use it for your predictions

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by simply entering into the darknet directory `%cd darkent`.